# Unable to Connect to DB2 Tables in Access that are Accessible in Excel

Tags: database, vba, ms-access, db2, ms-access-2007

I am trying to link a DB2 table in Access 2007 to recreate a query already made in Excel. The problem I am running into is that when I use `import data -> Link data -> Select DSN from Machine Data Source -> Enter Password` to connect using ODBC, the tables I need are not listed. I also tried to link to the table through VBA by using the code below which uses the exact same connection string as the Excel connection that works:

```
DoCmd.TransferDatabase acLink, "ODBC Database", _
     "ODBC;DSN=MyDSN;UID=UserName;PWD=Password;MODE=SHARE;DBALIAS=MyDSN;" _
      & "SCHEMALIST='ARS','BOM','DBA','FCS','HR','INT','INV','LCA','LCT','LCZ'," _
      & "'PCA','PCM','PCT','PTN','PUR','QCA','QCM','QCT','QCW','QXX','TIX','TSS'," _
      & "'UCX','WAR';", acTable, "RCX.RXSAL1", "DB2_RXSAL1"
```

Which just results in:

> run-time error 3011: The Microsoft Office Access database engine could not find the object 'RCX.RXSAL1'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly.

I think *RCX* not being in the schema list might be preventing Access from showing it when I try the import, but I don't understand why it wouldn't let me connect to it directly using VBA. Also, when I set up the query in Excel, I was able to bypass the table selection and just write the query directly, but it didn't show the table I need in the list of available tables there either.

Edit per Parfait's request:

Working query in excel:

```
select distinct
SupLookup.Sup_Num,
suplookup.CONTAINER_CODE,
AllocationType.ALLOC_TYPE_DESC,
Allocation.ALLOC_QTY,
Allocation.SAFE_STOCK_QTY,
Allocation.ALLOC_QTY + Allocation.SAFE_STOCK_QTY AS TOT_ALLOC_REQ_QTY

from RCX.RXSAL1 Allocation
inner join rcx.RXALT1 AllocationType on Allocation.ALLOC_TYPE_ID = AllocationType.ALLOC_TYPE_ID
left join
(select distinct
    SUPPLIER_ID,
    concat(SUPPLIER_NO, SUPPLIER_LOCATION) as Sup_Num,
    CONTAINER_CODE,
    CONTAINER_TYPE_ID
from rcx.RXPIR1    
where PLANT_ID= '00000001'
) as SupLookup on Allocation.SUPPLIER_ID = suplookup.SUPPLIER_ID and allocation.CONTAINER_TYPE_ID = suplookup.CONTAINER_TYPE_ID

where Allocation.PLANT_ID= '00000001'

ORDER BY Sup_Num ASC
```

Connection String in Excel:

`DSN=MyDSN;UID=UserName;PWD=Password;MODE=SHARE;DBALIAS=MyDSN;SCHEMALIST='ARS','BOM','DBA','FCS','HR','INT','INV','LCA','LCT','LCZ','PCA','PCM','PCT','PTN','PUR','QCA','QCM','QCT','QCW','QXX','TIX','TSS','UCX','WAR';`

Edit 2:

Excel query is input the following way:

Data Tab -> Select From Other Sources:From Microsoft Query in the Get External Data section -> Connect to DSN from list->enter username and password -> Close the Choose Columns Dialog -> Say "Yes" to continue editing in MS query -> Close the choose tables dialog -> Click the SQL button in MS query to view SQL -> paste in query -> Click OK -> Click Return Data button in MS query -> Select location for results.

The query then runs and puts data into the spreadsheet. The Connections button in the data tab allows you to get properties for these queries including the connection string.

Comment: Please show the code block of working query and connection in Excel even if you say it is exactly the same. How it is setup can help figure out the problem.

Comment: Clarify what you mean "tables are not listed". Of the 24 schemas in your SCHEMALIST, are any of the tables in those schemas listed?  If you add RCX to the SCHEMALIST , does the symptom change?   Does the symptom change if you *from inside Access* create a new additional DSN with new alias, to reference the Db2-database (leaving the original DSN untouched) ?

Comment: Yes, all but 1 of the schemas listed have at least one table associated with it. I tried adding RCX to the schema list in the connection string but it still gives me the same error. I do not have the appropriate privileges to create or change DSNs so I can't make a new one.

Comment: Thank you for update but where are you using this query and connection string in Excel? Notice I asked for *code block* (not snippets), so I can see implementation like ADO.

Comment: @Parfait Please see edit 2. There is no code because the query isn't made with VBA.

Comment: I think it might be useful to know which ODBC driver you are using to access DB2. I am just wondering whether you might be using an IBM i (DB2/400) ODBC driver & whether just possibly Access may not have told it to use SQL naming (.) rather than system naming (/). If that were the case, then RCX.RXSAL1 would be interpreted as the name of a table somewhere in the schema list, which wouldn't exist, presumably. (Easily tested by trying RCX/RXSAL1.)

Comment: Changing the (.) to (/) didn't work. Also, I have 3 different ODBC drivers (IBM DB2 ODBC Driver, IBM DB2 ODBC Driver-DB2_32bit, and Microsoft ODBC for Oracle) so I'm not sure which one Access would be using as a default.